# Split strings from integers from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code part of viewing a text file with a list of highscores and putting them into a list. i need to then split the string and integers.

```
OutList = input("Which class score would you like to view? ").upper()

if OutList == 'A':
    List = open("classA.txt").readlines()
    print (List)

elif OutList == 'B':
    List = open("classB.txt").readlines()
    print (List)

elif OutList == 'C':
    List = open("classC.txt").readlines()
    print (List)
```

This code currently prints this:

```
['Bobby 6\n', 'Thomas 4\n']
```

I need to know how to separate these and get rid of the '\n' to just have the name and score printed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rstrip()`

Here is your modified program:

```
OutList = input("Which class score would you like to view? ").upper()

if OutList == 'A':
    List = open("classA.txt").readlines()
    print (List)

elif OutList == 'B':
    List = open("classB.txt").readlines()
    print (List)

elif OutList == 'C':
    List = open("classC.txt").readlines()

for item in List:
    print(item.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
Which class score would you like to view? A
['Bobby 6\n', 'Thomas 4\n']
Bobby 6
Thomas 4
```

You can read more on rstrip function [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm).